# How can I create a PDF from Visual Studio C# with web form

Tags: model-view-controller

I have this question, I have a registration form in my webpage (view), I need to send this form to a email and also create a PDF with the information that the user typed in the form.

I am using Visual Studio 2013 C# MVC, and the form is in a view

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean a FREE way?  Most PDF converters cost money, but if it's simple, you can probably get by with library that'll do it:

[iTextSharp](https://www.nuget.org/packages/iTextSharp/)